# Remove street numbers from OSM maps

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

I'm still working on my map project. I use mapnik tools to render my own maps.
Mapnik reads a xml file to style each tiles.

At this moment, i managed to remove street names and all stuff that was useless for my project. The only problem i have is about removing the street numbers, which still appear even when all useless layers are off.

I give you a pastebin link to my xml file: http://pastebin.com/ZRtmYBRz.

Do you know how i can remove the street numbers ? Thanks.

Before :
[image: My tile, before]

Now:
[image: My tile, now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a filter on the `addr:housenumber` tag of the nodes in the source file that contain that info. Once you get those, you can change the rendering by using a `TextSymbolizer`.
More info on https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/TextSymbolizer

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was, in my opinion, a logic way to achieve this.

Another solution i found was to delete all the addr:housenumber values in my sql database, but it takes a lot of time.